# Create an html table dynamically with PHP loops

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops

This is a PHP array that has to be presented in a tabular format:

```
array:100 [▼
  "Brand #1" => array:3 [▼
  "2000" => "750.00"
  "2001" => "1750.00" 
  ..  
  ]
  "Brand #2" => array:3 [▼
    "2000" => "845.00"
    "2001" => "945.00"
    ..
  ]
  ..
  ..
```

The table should look like this:

[image]

I've been trying hard to present the data from the array in the table format using a bunch of PHP loops, but after several hours I came to a conclusion that it is not possible to generate a table like the one shown above without splitting the array into two separate data sources.

Am I right, or is there a way to achieve the desired output?

**EDIT:**

I think some users did not get the gist of the question hence these hastily downvotes.

I admit, I was not detailed enough.

Please notice that the dates  (from 2000 to 2004) will be repeated 100 times for every record in the top-level array. The table has only one set of dates (the first column).

Therefore, I wanted to support or rebuke my conclusion that such a table cannot be generated out of the provided data source AS IS.

Comment: what have you tried so far? where is your code? the simplest solution as for me would be build multidimensional array where first key is year and second brand `$arr[$year][$brandName] = $val`

Comment: There is always a way. If you have control over the PHP array, then I would organize the data the way you want it in a multi-dimensional array. Then your output can just loop through each row and display it.

Comment: If you have a database (mysql), you can put your information in it and create a while loop calling row arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of your array is not ideal, but we'll give it a go. 
Let's assume we have the data below:

```
$data = array(
    "Brand #1" => array(
        "2000" => "750.00",
        "2001" => "1750.00" 
  ),
    "Brand #2" => array(
        "2000" => "845.00",
        "2001" => "945.00",
        "2002" => "970.00"
  )
);

/* find all years */
$years = array();
foreach($data as $brand) {
    foreach($brand as $year => $value) {
        if(!in_array($year,$years)) $years[] = $year;
    }
}
sort($years);
```

We have now all the unique years in the array `$years`.
Loop through every year and look up the value for every brand in a loop like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <!-- generate table headers -->
        <th>Year</th>
        <?php foreach($data as $brand => $year): ?>
            <th><?php echo $brand; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>

    <!-- for each year create a new row in the table -->
    <?php foreach($years as $year): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $year; ?></td>

        <!-- and for every brand we create a entry in the column -->
        <?php foreach($data as $brand): ?>
        <td><?php echo isset($brand[$year]) ? $brand[$year] : "";?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

If this does not meet you requirements, please clearify and I'll try to answer.

Comment: Nicely done. Might want to throw a `sort($years);` in there after finding all years, in case year 1 might not have the lowest year.

Comment: @msfoster, I have just tested you code. Works perfectly! Thank you for taking your time to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the years to work out. Thought I'd post my solution here anyway even though it's not complete.

```
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";

$year = 2000;

echo "<tr>";
echo "  <th style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "    Year";    

$show = 1;

// gives us brand 1, brand 2, brand 3, etc
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{

    echo "  <th style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
    echo $key;
    echo "    <table>";

    // gives years 2000, 2001, 2002, etc
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {
        echo "<tr>";

        if($show)
        {

            echo "<td style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
            echo $year + $i;
            echo "</td>";

        }

        // gives the actual values 
        echo "<td style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
        echo $array[$key][$year+$i];
        echo "</td>";

    }

    $show = 0;

    echo "    </table>";
    echo "  </th>";


}
```

Comment: You are creating tables within tables.